# Обоснованно ли применение полей типа DOUBLE для целых чисел?

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Один "товарищ" при создании таблицы в БД использовал поле типа DOUBLE для хранения числа в диапазоне от-100 до 1000 (Макс. 2000), т.е. остатка товара на складе не очень большого магазина, для чисел явно являющихся целыми.

Я считаю, что это просто проявление полной безграмотности человека в представлении формата чисел. Или я не прав? Разъясните, так как данный человек в свою очередь заявляет о моей некомпетентности.

**Уточнение по вопросу:**

*DOUBLE точность до 15 знаков после запятой. Товар точно не весовой. Даже весов никогда небыло в магазине. Это авто-запчасти.*

Comment: @ХэшКод, в названии еще одна ошибка осталась.. (сам исправить не могу)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не вижу никакой особенной трагедии в том, что был использован формат DOUBLE для хранения целых чисел. Ну занимает чуток больше пространства - ну и что? Вместо 2 байт - будет 8 байт, подумаешь. Это раньше когда оперативная память 8 кбайт было много, а емкость диска мегабайт рассматривалась как роскошь тогда можно было чего-то оптимизировать.

Зато появляется некая универсальность, кто его знает вдруг ваш магазинчик через пару-тройку лет начнет торговать моторным маслом в рОзлив. Хороший прогер должен на уровне архитектуры предусмотреть возможные вывихи в будущем.

В общем это не является преступлением, равно как и не является показателем квалификации. Лучше посмотрите на нормальность данных - если они плохо нормализованы - это действительно преступление.

Comment: А поля типа float использовать, что не позволяет? Всегда их использовал для плавающих запятых. Там и точность 6 знаков после запятой, вроде приемлема.

Comment: @I_CaR, практика показывает, что с `float` изредка возникают неожданные проблемы с точностью, а с `double` нет.

Comment: Возникают. Теория рассказывает, что float и double различаются только числом бит. Да, у float 24 бита мантиссы, а у decimal — 53. Т.е. проблемы с точностью у double наступят обязательно, просто на несколько больших величинах.

Comment: Тогда просто возникающий вопрос, не повлияет ли данный тип поля на множественное обращение к нем через SQL запрос, всмысле времени его выполнения?
Запрос пока 3000*7 строк по 2 поля. Глубокими знаниями математики и SQL не могу :(

Answer (score 4):

Я когда интересовался, как хранить стоимость услуг, во float, или decimal, папки советовали хранить в decimal, ибо храня инфу во float у бухгалтерии внезапно могут вопросы возникнуть. Типа, там точность вычисления может быть неправильной, если суммы большие будут, и Я с такими проблемами однажды как раз и столкнулся. Времени разбираться не было, просто последовал их совету, с тех пор проблем не имею в этом плане

Answer (score 3):

Можно-то оно можно, но не забывайте, что [123456789123456789123456789](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=049050051052053054055056057049050051052053054055056057049050051052053054055056057) будет представлено как 1.23456789123456791**337762816** × 10²⁶.

640 килобайт^W^W 53 бита мантиссы, конечно, хватает всем, но, как показывает практика, не навечно. Когда-нибудь да вылезете за пределы точности и не заметите.

Поэтому лучше возьмите decimal aka numeric. От вас не убудет, зато работать будет без тонкостей.

Answer (score 0):

Единственное объяснение -это в чем измеряются остатки и как продается товар. К примеру, сахар  измеряется в кг, а продать могут и 0,5 кг.

Хорошо. Допустим, занялись продажей масла (в бочках) на розлив, к примеру, пришло 200 л, продали 0.5. Или, к примеру, занялись они продажей проводов для установки звука. Приходят они тоже метрами, а продать могут метр с лишним, или 0,5 метров.
По поводу точности - так там настроить можно количество знаков после запятой.

Вообще, скорее всего, он сделал так специально, так как никто с уверенностью 100% ему не смог сказать что товар будет измерятся только штуками, а не литрами к примеру.

Comment: Но ведь в DOUBLE точность до 15 знаков после запятой. И это товар точно не весовой. Даже весов никогда небыло в магазине. Это авто-запчасти.